# Iframe with subdomain as target won't load.

Tags: html, wordpress, security, iframe, content-security-policy

I've been trying to load an iframe into my website but it won't work and Chrome console shows this error message:

> Refused to display 'https://viewtrip.travelport.com/#!/itinerary?loc=xxx' in a frame because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors https://viewtripnextgen-api.travelport.com".

I also tried to add `https://viewtripnextgen-api.travelport.com` as frame ancestor but it doesn't to any difference. I really clueless on how to solve this issue.

Comment: "I also tried to add https://viewtripnextgen-api.travelport.com as frame ancestor" — How?

Comment: What do you mean, you tried to add it as a frame ancestor? It _is_ already added to the value for the directive. The page you are trying to embed the iframe _on_ is not from `https://viewtripnextgen-api.travelport.com/`, that is what that error message is trying to tell you. If anything, you would need to add the base URL of _that_ as an allowed origin.

Comment: Quentin - I added this piece "Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors <source>;" to my htacess file.

Comment: The link are an itinerary for a customer so I edited the link so it wouldn't show the customers personal details.

Comment: @MichaelM — Does your `.htaccess` file live on the server for `'https://viewtrip.travelport.com/`?

Comment: Another thing to mention, I don't have any experience on this topic, so if I don't make sense please let me know

Comment: @Quentin It does not. I think I've misunderstood how it works. It is travelport who has to "accept" me in their policy and not otherwise, right?

Comment: @MichaelM — Yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message means that you may **only** display that page in an iframe if your `<iframe>` tag appears on a page at the URL `https://viewtripnextgen-api.travelport.com`.

> I also tried to add https://viewtripnextgen-api.travelport.com as frame ancestor

The only way you can do this is if you run the `travelport.com` website.

The only other option would be to change the CSP of `https://viewtrip.travelport.com`, which you can also do only if you run the `travelport.com` website.

As a third party who wants to put someone else's content in your iframe, if they say no (which they are), then you can't do it.

Comment: That makes completely sense for me. 
So if I want travelport.com displayed in an iframe on my website, I actually have to contact them an ask them add my domain as trusted in their CSP?

Comment: @MichaelM — Correct.